# Filtering one List<string> from another via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a master list of colors:

```
List<string> completeList = new List<string>{"red", "blue", "green", "purple"};
```

I'm passing in a List of existing colors of a product

```
List<string> actualColors = new List<string>{"blue", "red", "green"};
```

How do I get a list back that is in the order of the completeList? (red,blue,green)

Answer (score 16):

```
var ordered = completeList.Intersect(actualColors);
```

If that doesn't work, do this

```
var ordered = actualColors.Intersect(completeList);
```

Comment: Linq also has `Union` too and a bunch of awesome features.

Comment: I'm not sure Intersect() guarantees stable ordering according to the left sequence. The implementation probably uses a hash join which means it might honor the sequence of one of the operands, but I'm not sure it's specifically the left. For all you know, it could be actualColors.Intersect(completeList) which yields an equivalent (sans ordering) sequence.

Comment: @Avish. According to msdn it is:

"When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Intersect enumerates first, collecting all distinct elements of that sequence. It then enumerates second, marking those elements that occur in both sequences. Finally, the marked elements are yielded in the order in which they were collected."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx